# Problemas con inserción y actualización

Tags: php, pdo

Tengo las siguientes tablas:

**trasvalores:**
id_trasvalores,
monto_trasvalores_apertura,
monto_trasvalores_actual,
monto_trasvalores_cierre,
fecha,
id_usuarios

**transferencias:**
id_transferencias,
n_transferencia,
fecha,
hora,
monto_trasferido,
porcentaje,
ganancia,
total,
id_usuarios,
id_bancos_admin,
id_cuentas_admin,
id_clientes,
id_bancos,
id_cuentas,
portada,
status

Ahora lo que necesito hacer es lo siguiente:

La tabla **trasvalores** es para ingresar montos por día, ejemplo: el admin hoy ingreso un monto de **100$.** que seria el monto para iniciar el día de trabajo

Ahora la tabla **transferencias:** para qué sirve, esta tabla es para realizar transferencias a clientes lo que quiero lograr es que cuando se haga una trasferencia se vaya actualizando en la tabla trasvolares; ejemplo si tengo en trasvolares un monto de **100$** y hice una transferencia de 20$ ya me debe quedar **80$** disponibles en trasvolares, lo que se tendría que actualizar cada vez que se haga una transferencia sería el monto_trasvalores_actual de la tabla trasvalores, pero antes de hacer la inserción debería hacer una consulta a la tabla trasvalores si hay fondo disponibles si hay se ejecuta el código de lo contrario debería mandar a recargar trasvalores para poder seguir realizando transferencias. Hasta el momento tengo esto.

```
  <!-- proceso para registrar-->
  <?php
  if(isset($_POST['guardar'])){


  $sql = "SELECT monto_trasvalores_actual FROM trasvalores WHERE monto_trasvalores_actual = :monto_trasvalores_actual LIMIT 1"; //Creamos la select
  $check = $DB_con->prepare($sql); //Preparamos la SELECT, de ésta manera evitamos SQL Injection
  $check->bindParam(':monto_trasvalores_actual', $_POST['monto_trasvalores_actual']);//Substituimos las variables de la SELECT
  $check->execute();//Ejecutamos la consulta
  $contador = $check -> rowCount();//Esta función devuelve el número de resultados que ha devuelto la SELECT
  if ($contador > 2000) {
  $check->closeCursor();

          $errMSG = "¡ Ups Aviso: trasvalores insuficiente Por favor Actualize el monto!";

}

else

{


$imgFile = $_FILES['portada']['name'];
$tmp_dir = $_FILES['portada']['tmp_name'];
$imgSize = $_FILES['portada']['size'];

  $upload_dir = '../galerias_transferencias/'; // upload directory

  $imgExt = strtolower(pathinfo($imgFile,PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); // get image extension

  // valid image extensions
  $valid_extensions = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif'); // valid extensions

  // rename uploading image
  $portada = rand(1000,1000000).".".$imgExt;

  // allow valid image file formats
  if(in_array($imgExt, $valid_extensions)){     
    // Check file size '5MB'
    if($imgSize < 5000000)        {
      move_uploaded_file($tmp_dir,$upload_dir.$portada);
    }
    else{

    $errMSG = "¡ Lo siento, su archivo es demasiado grande !";
    }
  }
  else{

  $errMSG = "¡ Lo sentimos, sólo se permiten archivos JPG, JPEG, PNG y GIF !";
  }

// si no hay errores continuo...

  $sql = "SELECT  n_transferencia FROM transferencias WHERE   n_transferencia = :n_transferencia LIMIT 1"; //Creamos la select
  $check = $DB_con->prepare($sql); //Preparamos la SELECT, de ésta manera evitamos SQL Injection
   $check->bindParam(':n_transferencia', 
   $_POST['n_transferencia']);//Substituimos las variables de la SELECT
   $check->execute();//Ejecutamos la consulta
   $contador = $check -> rowCount();//Esta función devuelve el número de resultados que ha devuelto la SELECT
   if ($contador > 0) {
   $check->closeCursor();

          $errMSG = "¡ Ups Aviso: El Registro ya se Encuentra Insertado !";

    }
    else
    {

   $sql=$DB_con->prepare("INSERT INTO transferencias (n_transferencia,fecha,hora,monto_trasferido,porcentaje,ganancia,total,id_usuarios,id_bancos_admin,id_cuentas_admin,id_clientes,id_bancos,id_cuentas,portada,status) VALUES (:n_transferencia,:fecha,:hora,:monto_trasferido,:porcentaje,:ganancia,:total,:id_usuarios,:id_bancos_admin,:id_cuentas_admin,:id_clientes,:id_bancos,:id_cuentas,:portada,:status)");
   $sql->bindParam(':n_transferencia', $_POST['n_transferencia']);
   $sql->bindParam(':fecha', $_POST['fecha']);
   $sql->bindParam(':hora', $_POST['hora']);
   $sql->bindParam(':monto_trasferido', $_POST['monto_trasferido']);
   $sql->bindParam(':porcentaje', $_POST['porcentaje']);
   $sql->bindParam(':ganancia', $_POST['ganancia']);
   $sql->bindParam(':total', $_POST['total']);
   $sql->bindParam(':id_usuarios', $_POST['id_usuarios']);
   $sql->bindParam(':id_bancos_admin', $_POST['id_bancos_admin']);
   $sql->bindParam(':id_cuentas_admin', $_POST['id_cuentas_admin']);
   $sql->bindParam(':id_clientes', $_POST['id_clientes']);
   $sql->bindParam(':id_bancos', $_POST['id_bancos']);
   $sql->bindParam(':id_cuentas', $_POST['id_cuentas']);
   $sql->bindParam(':portada', $portada);
   $sql->bindParam(':status', $_POST['status']);
   $sql->execute();

   $successMSG ="¡ Bien Hecho: Registro Insertado Correctamente !";


   $monto_trasferido= 0;

   $sql2 = "UPDATE trasvalores SET monto_trasferido=:monto_trasvalores_actual WHERE monto_trasvalores_actual=:monto_trasvalores_actual;";   
    $sql2=$DB_con->prepare($sql2);
    $sql2->bindValue(":monto_trasvalores_actual",$monto_trasvalores_actual);

    if ($sql2 ->execute())
    {
    //echo "Se actualizaron ".$sql2->rowCount()." registros";
    }
   else 
   {
    //echo "Los registros no se  actualizaron";
    }

           }

   }
   }
   ?>
  <!-- fin proceso para registrar-->
```

Pido mil disculpa si mi post se parece a otro que hice lo que paso es que decidí cerrarlo porque no se como editarlo y quitar los comentarios, en fin aquí mi problema.

Comment: ¿Realmente te interesa tener un campo que va a cambiar constantemente y que puedes obtener dinámicamente calculando la diferencia entre otras dos columnas de la tabla, por ejemplo `columna1-columna2=resultado_dinamico`?  ¿Cuál es el motivo para guardar ese campo en una columna a la cual vas a tener que estar haciendo `UPDATE` constantemente.  ¿Y si falla algún `UPDATE` y el valor queda establecido a cero, o a otro valor que no es el real?

Comment: gracias amigo por tu respuesta, pero el motivo es el siguiente que el administrador ingresa un monto diario y el quiere llevar el control de lo gastado de ese monto y como se gasta ese monto con registros de transferencias me explico yo de mi bolsillo he puesto un saldo de 500$ ahora a esos 500$ yo debo sacarle una ganancia es como decir voy a poner a trabajar mi dinero, entonces tengo mis 500$ registrados en el sistema ahora si hago una trasferencias de 100$ ya me quedarian disponibles 400$ para seguir haciendo transferencias si el monto llega a un monto mínimo establecido debe mandar

Comment: a actualizar el monto para seguir haciendo transferencias ya que no se puede volver a registrar porque el trasvalor debe insertarse diariamente,

Comment: Como comenta el compañero @acedano estas planteando malamente la base de datos. En lugar de hacer update deberías de crear otra inserción con el valor en negativo, luego haces un SUM y obtienes en monto actual. Para lo que comentas seria recomendable utilizar transacciones. Da igual que el valor sea diario o tenga otra periocidad. Imagina una tabla stock, cada registro será una entrada o salida de stock, la suma de los registros te dará el stock actual.

Comment: pero en este caso ya la tabla existe que seria transferencias donde registro todos los montos ejecutados de las transferencias, me comentaron también que es mejor crear un trigger no se si es buena idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

en fin lo pude resolver y como lo resolvi con un disparador:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `nuevotrasvalor` AFTER INSERT ON `adelantos`
FOR EACH ROW UPDATE trasvalores SET monto_trasvalores_actual = 
(monto_trasvalores_actual-NEW.monto) WHERE DATE(trasvalores.fecha) = CURDATE()
```