# insertar e actualizar monto actual con el nuevo monto

Tags: php, pdo

Quisiera sus opiniones de que es lo más recomendable hacer en este caso: primero tengo una tabla trasvalores que es donde se registran los montos a diarios.

**trasvalores:**
Id_trasvalores
monto_trasvalores_apertura
monto_trasvalores_actual
fecha
hora
id_usuarios
entregado
recibido
lugar_origen

**denominaciones:**
id_denominacion
denominacion
cantidad
monto
id_trasvalores

**proceso para registrar**

```
<!-- proceso para registrar-->

<?php
 if(isset($_POST['guardar'])){


 $sql = "SELECT fecha FROM trasvalores WHERE fecha = :fecha LIMIT 1"; 
 //Creamos la select
 $check = $DB_con->prepare($sql); //Preparamos la SELECT, de ésta manera evitamos SQL Injection
 $check->bindParam(':fecha', $_POST['fecha']);//Substituimos las variables de la SELECT
 $check->execute();//Ejecutamos la consulta
 $contador = $check -> rowCount();//Esta función devuelve el número de resultados que ha devuelto la SELECT
 if ($contador > 0) {
 $check->closeCursor();

          $errMSG = "¡ Ups Aviso: El Registro ya se Encuentra Insertado !";

 }
  else
 {


  $sql=$DB_con->prepare("INSERT INTO trasvalores (monto_trasvalores_apertura,monto_trasvalores_actual,fecha,id_usuarios,entregado,recibido,lugar_origen) VALUES ( :monto_trasvalores_apertura,:monto_trasvalores_apertura,:fecha,:id_usuarios,:entregado,:recibido,:lugar_origen)");
  $sql->bindParam(':monto_trasvalores_apertura', 
  $_POST['monto_trasvalores_apertura']);
  $sql->bindParam(':monto_trasvalores_actual', 
  $_POST['monto_trasvalores_apertura']);
  $sql->bindParam(':fecha', $_POST['fecha']);
  $sql->bindParam(':id_usuarios', $_POST['id_usuarios']);
  $sql->bindParam(':entregado', $_POST['entregado']);
  $sql->bindParam(':recibido', $_POST['recibido']);
  $sql->bindParam(':lugar_origen', $_POST['lugar_origen']);
  $sql->execute();
  $last_id = $DB_con->lastInsertId();

  for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['denominacion']); $i++) {

      for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['cantidad']); $i++) {

          for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['monto']); $i++) {

    $sql2=$DB_con->prepare("INSERT INTO denominaciones (id_trasvalores, denominacion,cantidad,monto) VALUES (:id_trasvalores,:denominacion, :cantidad, :monto)");
  $sql2->bindParam(':id_trasvalores', $last_id);
  $sql2->bindParam(':denominacion', $_POST['denominacion'][$i]);
  $sql2->bindParam(':cantidad', $_POST['cantidad'][$i]);
  $sql2->bindParam(':monto', $_POST['monto'][$i]);

    $sql2->execute();

          $successMSG ="¡ Bien Hecho: Registro Insertado Correctamente !";


                      } 

                   } 
              } 
          }
      }
   ?>
   <!-- fin proceso para registrar-->
```

ahora cual es el problema que si tengo un monto aperturado de x valor ejemplo tengo un monto aperturado de 10000 y quiero hacer otra insersión el campo monto_trasvalores_apertura y monto_trasvalores_actual deben actualizarse con el monto que se registrara nuevamente ejemplo me queda 10000 y voy hacer un nuevo registro por 30000 en total deberia haber ahora con la nueva insersión 40000 disponible.

Comment: Amigo, yo sigo pensando [lo que te comenté en esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/86873/29967). Puedes conocer eso calculando entre dos campos de la base de datos. Almacenar un valor que cambia constantemente no me parece una buena idea en este caso. Si de todos modos decides hacerlo, tienes que establecer muchos controles para que el dato no se actualice erróneamente, pues te fastidiaría todo. Por cierto, ¿qué ocurrió [con tu problema de la hora](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/86777/problemas-al-guardar-hora)?, me quedé con la curiosidad de lo que estaba pasando. Saludos.

Comment: la primera pregunta  lo resolvi con un disparador y la segunda pregunta no lo he resuleto

Comment: A. Cedano si puedes invitarme a una sala para así entender mejor las ideas